# Save Parent - Child Hierarchy for same SObject in a single DML

Tags: sobject, dml, parent-to-child

I want to save the lookup relationship for same object in a single DML statement, so basically I want to do [something similar like this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm) but for same `Sobject`, I have found one article [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-Upsert-parent-and-child-in-single-DML-using-their-own-externalids-apex-salesforce)  but this is not working.

Is it possible ,if yes how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cant use single DML statement to insert both parent and child which belong to same Sobject.

To back that up I have also added link to document.

> You can’t add a record that references another record of the same object type in the same call. For example, the Contact object has a Reports To field that’s a reference to another contact. You can’t create two contacts in one call if one contact uses the Reports To field to reference a second contact in the input array. You can create a contact that references another contact that has been previously created.

Link to document - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_limitations.htm

Comment: This is actually possible, but so impractical that it might as well be impossible. If you use an external id field and have the parent and child records separated by at least 200 entries in the List (to guarantee that the parent and child are inserted in different trigger chunks, and the parent is inserted first), it'll work. I think using the "Unit of Work" class from fflib (Apex Enterprise Patterns) to manage the insert of the parent + children would probably be the way to go.

Comment: @derek I will certainly look into it. Didnt know such thing existed in first place

Comment: It's one of those things that you tend to figure out if you keep poking at things for long enough. Again though, it's very impractical.

Comment: Well I guess I need to learn to poke to know all the niche abilities/disabilities  in the system as well.